# how to measure $Tr[M\rho_1N\rho_2]$ on NISQ devices?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

To evaluate $Tr[M\rho]$ with $M$ and $\rho$ a tensor product of Pauli operators and a density matrix, respectively, we just need to prepare the state $\rho$ and then measure it in the $M$-eigenbasis.

Then how to evaluate $Tr[\rho_1\rho_2]$ on NISQ devices? I considered using the SWAP test and it works, but it requires controlled-SWAP operations, which is not achievable on NISQ devices, where only two-qubit gates between couped-qubits can be applied.

Comment: It's not quite accurate that controlled-swap (aka CSWAP) cannot be implemented on todays devices. It is correct that quantum computers typically support a small but universal set of 1 and 2 qubit operations. However the idea is that you would compile 3+ qubit gates down so that they are implemented in terms of 1 and 2 qubit gates.

Comment: So on IBM devices you would implement the 3 qubit CSWAP in terms of {X, SX, Rz, CX} gates. If your base gateset is universal you can always do this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Indeed any unitary operation can be decomposed into 1- and 2-qubit gates from the universal gate set. However, the resulting gate sequence would be deep for NISQ devices, so as the requirement for the connectivity between physical qubits. Then I am considering other methods.